# Fingerprint Scanner Selection

Tags: arduino, fingerprint

I'm interested in which fingerprint scanner to use in a project with arduino or raspberry pi. This scanner MUST ONLY take the picture of the fingerprint and not to process neither validate the fingerprint because all of this will be done in a computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try an R305 module. It is one of the more popular modules with communication over UART. Adafruit has an existing library though it does not cover image download. However, there's substantial documentation that contains all the commands including the command for extracting the images you need. An image is usually a sort of compressed 256x288 grayscale BMP and is typically 37kB in size. You'll need to extrapolate to get the complete 74kB image. You should keep in mind that the maximum baud rate is 115200 or 11.5kB/s so it will take about 4 seconds to download an image before you can begin processing it. An Arduino would be unreliable at that baud rate too.

Another module that is completely compatible with the R305 is the FPM10 module; all the commands are the same and they are easily interchangeable. [Here's](https://www.academia.edu/19017862/FPM10_R305_Fingerprint_Sensor_Interfacing_with_Arduino) a tutorial that can help.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @TisteAndii How can I extrapolate the 37kb image to 74kb? Could you please help out. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @VishnooRath Well, the way *I* did it was to split each byte into 2 4-bit nibbles and then extend each nibble with zeros to become a full byte. That is, 10101111 becomes 10100000 and 00001111. This got me an image well enough but a better way would probably be to simply duplicate each byte since nearby pixels will most likely have the same colour (or nearly) and the lower 4 bits dont have as much effect on the overall colour as the upper 4 bits. So 10101111 simply becomes 10101111 and 10101111.